# How can I merge two dataframes by time when they have different times

Tags: database, time, merge, range, conditional-statements

I need some help, please. I need to merge by the TIME two databases, but I do not know-how.

The database 1 (Amphibian) is composed of observation every 5 seconds.

```
DATE    TIME    CDOM    Chl LAT LONG
9/13/2019   9:00:01 AM  81.6    16.39   29.908773   -90.272686
9/13/2019   9:00:06 AM  81.56   16.31   29.908773   -90.272686
9/13/2019   9:00:11 AM  81.5    16.19   29.908772   -90.272686
9/13/2019   9:00:16 AM  81.4    16.62   29.908772   -90.272686
9/13/2019   9:00:21 AM  81.45   16.88   29.908772   -90.272686
9/13/2019   9:04:51 AM  81.18   17.37   29.908586   -90.272663
9/13/2019   9:04:56 AM  81.22   17.57   29.90856    -90.272673
9/13/2019   9:05:01 AM  81.25   17.6    29.908522   -90.272668
9/13/2019   9:05:06 AM  81.28   17.66   29.908482   -90.272647
9/13/2019   9:05:11 AM  81.11   17.39   29.908434   -90.272621
9/13/2019   9:05:16 AM  81.13   17.08   29.90838    -90.272595
9/13/2019   9:05:21 AM  80.95   16.99   29.908323   -90.272568
9/13/2019   9:05:26 AM  80.93   17.5    29.908265   -90.27254
9/13/2019   9:05:31 AM  80.81   17.1    29.908209   -90.272523
9/13/2019   9:05:36 AM  80.84   17.29   29.908152   -90.272504
9/13/2019   9:05:41 AM  80.85   17.85   29.908089   -90.272491
9/13/2019   9:05:46 AM  80.84   17.41   29.908029   -90.272485
9/13/2019   9:05:51 AM  80.96   18.21   29.907968   -90.272471
9/13/2019   9:05:56 AM  80.83   17.88   29.907914   -90.272442
```

The database 2 is composed of observations every 10 seconds.

```
DATE    TIME    pCO2
9/13/2019   8:59:57 AM  851.45
9/13/2019   9:00:09 AM  854.42
9/13/2019   9:00:20 AM  856.61
9/13/2019   9:04:56 AM  931.6
9/13/2019   9:05:07 AM  935.23
9/13/2019   9:05:18 AM  940.03
9/13/2019   9:05:29 AM  942.46
9/13/2019   9:05:40 AM  947.5
9/13/2019   9:05:51 AM  949.54
```

I want to combine both databases, matching the values of pCO2 with the columns that have the same TIME in the Amphibian, but also for those pCO2 TIMES that do not match, I want to match them with the Amphibian values, within a range of the previous 5 seconds of the Amphibian database #1.

Expected results:

```
DATE    TIME    CDOM    Chl LAT LONG    pCO2
9/13/2019   9:00:01 AM  81.6    16.39   29.908773   -90.272686  NA
9/13/2019   9:00:06 AM  81.56   16.31   29.908773   -90.272686  854.42
9/13/2019   9:00:11 AM  81.5    16.19   29.908772   -90.272686  NA
9/13/2019   9:00:16 AM  81.4    16.62   29.908772   -90.272686  856.61
9/13/2019   9:00:21 AM  81.45   16.88   29.908772   -90.272686  NA
9/13/2019   9:04:51 AM  81.18   17.37   29.908586   -90.272663  NA
9/13/2019   9:04:56 AM  81.22   17.57   29.90856    -90.272673  931.6
9/13/2019   9:05:01 AM  81.25   17.6    29.908522   -90.272668  NA
9/13/2019   9:05:06 AM  81.28   17.66   29.908482   -90.272647  935.23
9/13/2019   9:05:11 AM  81.11   17.39   29.908434   -90.272621  NA
9/13/2019   9:05:16 AM  81.13   17.08   29.90838    -90.272595  940.03
9/13/2019   9:05:21 AM  80.95   16.99   29.908323   -90.272568  NA
9/13/2019   9:05:26 AM  80.93   17.5    29.908265   -90.27254   942.46
9/13/2019   9:05:31 AM  80.81   17.1    29.908209   -90.272523  NA
9/13/2019   9:05:36 AM  80.84   17.29   29.908152   -90.272504  947.5
9/13/2019   9:05:41 AM  80.85   17.85   29.908089   -90.272491  NA
9/13/2019   9:05:46 AM  80.84   17.41   29.908029   -90.272485  NA
9/13/2019   9:05:51 AM  80.96   18.21   29.907968   -90.272471  949.54
9/13/2019   9:05:56 AM  80.83   17.88   29.907914   -90.272442  NA
```

I was able to merge them, but I don't know how to merge them including the range/interval I need.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi there. Welcome to stackoverflow. For your next questions:try to format your code for better readability.

Comment: I Merc, can you read the database now? I think I just fixed it.

Comment: I did edit it for you, but I think the edit hat to be proof-read, so you were maybe quicker :).

Comment: I am absolutey no database master, but I think it would help to tell other people what kind of databases you got, in which format your data is. MySQL, MongoDB, csv files, Filemaker, whatever... And in which programming language you want to merge them...

Comment: Hi Merc, thank you so much. This databases are csv files. I would like to merge them using RStudio, but any suggestion is more than welcome.

Comment: Hm what I see, is that it is not «every 10 seconds» it's rather every 10-12 seconds. I think if you want to merge two data entries without any matching field (like TIME) it is not possible to do that for a machine.
You could probably round the TIME value to be less specific, but I think then to 10seconds somehow. `9:00:06` => `9:00:10` and do the same for your amphibians. This could result in two datasets with more matching TIME fields than now...